# Include a file in an Android application

Tags: json, android-studio, gmail-api, credentials

I used android studio to create a java app. In the project, I created the "assets" folder, and inside I put the json file that I will need to get the credentials for GmailAPI.

[AssetFolder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2ck9.jpg)

I wish I could access the json file. I have already tried in many ways but every time it tells me that the file is missing.
This is the code:

```
public class GmailApi {

public Gmail initService(String userId) throws GeneralSecurityException,
        IOException {

    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    final GoogleCredentials creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("gmailapi-android.json"))
            .createScoped(GmailScopes.GMAIL_SEND);
    final GoogleCredentials delegatedCreds = creds.createDelegated("xxx@xxx.com");
    HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(delegatedCreds);
    HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport.Builder().build();
    // Construct the gmail object.
    Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, requestInitializer)
            .setApplicationName("gmailapi")
            .build();

    return service;
}
}
```

Could anyone help me? What should I put in the path to be able to access the json file?

```
        final GoogleCredentials creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("gmailapi-android.json"))
```

Comment: Android Java isn't Java EE, which means this approach is doomed to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to open the file this way?

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
InputStream ims = assetManager.open("gmailapi-android.json");
```

Comment: Adding the lines I get the following error: Cannot resolve method 'getAssets' in 'GmailApi'

Comment: If your not in Activity you need a context for this method